# Bluetooth cannot connect to BT Keyboard

Tags: arch-linux, bluetooth, bluez, connectivity

I recently invested in a new Intel NUC and put Arch Linux on it. I also invested in a Keychron K6  however I have hit a brick wall when it comes to connecting to it via Bluetooth.

Here is what bluetoothctl gives...

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 0C:7A:15:C1:12:8F BlueZ 5.55 [default]
[bluetooth]# show
Controller 0C:7A:15:C1:12:8F (public)
    Name: BlueZ 5.55
    Alias: BlueZ 5.55
    Class: 0x00100104
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0537
    Discovering: no
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
    Roles: central-peripheral
Advertising Features:
    ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
    SupportedInstances: 0x06 (6)
    SupportedIncludes: tx-power
    SupportedIncludes: appearance
    SupportedIncludes: local-name
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: 1M
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: 2M
    SupportedSecondaryChannels: Coded
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller 0C:7A:15:C1:12:8F Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# devices
Device FC:58:FA:AF:A9:F4 Marsboy
Device DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30 Keychron K6
[bluetooth]# info DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30
Device DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30 (public)
    Name: Keychron K6
    Alias: Keychron K6
    Class: 0x00002540
    Icon: input-keyboard
    Paired: yes
    Trusted: yes
    Blocked: no
    Connected: no
    WakeAllowed: yes
    LegacyPairing: no
    UUID: Service Discovery Serve.. (00001000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Human Interface Device... (00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v05ACp024Fd011B
[CHG] Device DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30 RSSI: -51
[bluetooth]# connect DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30
Attempting to connect to DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30
[CHG] Device DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30 Connected: yes
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[CHG] Device DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30 Connected: no
```

This is what systemctl status bluetooth gives...

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-02-23 18:49:31 UTC; 1h 20min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 422 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 19032)
     Memory: 2.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─422 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Feb 23 18:59:47 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:ioctl_is_connected() Can't get HIDP connection info
Feb 23 18:59:48 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:control_connect_cb() connect to DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30: Permission denied (13)
Feb 23 18:59:51 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:ioctl_is_connected() Can't get HIDP connection info
Feb 23 18:59:52 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:control_connect_cb() connect to DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30: Permission denied (13)
Feb 23 19:34:14 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:ioctl_is_connected() Can't get HIDP connection info
Feb 23 19:34:19 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:control_connect_cb() connect to DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30: Host is down (112)
Feb 23 19:34:35 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:ioctl_is_connected() Can't get HIDP connection info
Feb 23 19:34:40 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:control_connect_cb() connect to DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30: Host is down (112)
Feb 23 19:56:02 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:ioctl_is_connected() Can't get HIDP connection info
Feb 23 19:56:04 archlinux bluetoothd[422]: profiles/input/device.c:control_connect_cb() connect to DC:2C:26:F3:D0:30: Permission denied (13)
```

Finally and if it helps here are the stats of the hardware and software installed on my machine...

`````
    OS: Arch Linux x86_64 
                `+oooo:                  Host: NUC8i5BEH J72747-307 
               `+oooooo:                 Kernel: 5.10.17-1-lts 
               -+oooooo+:                Uptime: 1 hour, 22 mins 
             `/:-:++oooo+:               Packages: 1234 (pacman), 1 (dpkg) 
            `/++++/+++++++:              Shell: zsh 5.8 
           `/++++++++++++++:             Resolution: 1920x1080, 1600x900 
          `/+++ooooooooooooo/`           DE: Plasma 5.21.0 
         ./ooosssso++osssssso+`          WM: KWin 
        .oossssso-````/ossssss+`         WM Theme: Breeze 
       -osssssso.      :ssssssso.        Theme: Infinity Dark Color [Plasma], B 
      :osssssss/        osssso+++.       Icons: BeautyLine [Plasma], BeautyLine 
     /ossssssss/        +ssssooo/-       Terminal: terminator 
   `/ossssso+/:-        -:/+osssso+-     CPU: Intel i5-8259U (8) @ 3.800GHz 
  `+sso+:-`                 `.-/+oso:    GPU: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 655 
 `++:.                           `-/+/   Memory: 4025MiB / 15875MiB
`````

Many thanks in advance.
Phillip

Answer (score 0):

Seem to have fixed it. All I did is just remove the device and then rescanned and it works. I have not rebooted yet but will see how that goes.

Comment: Can you please give more details about what you did that fixed the issue?  What command did you run and in what order?  Thanks.